# Is it possible to push data updates from elasticsearch?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, apache-kafka

I'm working on an application, which

1. Receives streaming key-value data from a data provider (When you connect to data provider it sends you all available data on first request and then data updates on further requests)
2. We dump this data to Kafka(using Kafka as a datastore)
3. This data is then pushed to ElasticSearch using LogStash(for enhanced querying and other capabilities)
4. We then have a NodeJS Server + ReactJS UI whose functionality is to 
   either display all available data 
                or 
   filter and display selective data based on user-specified key
   by fetching from elasticsearch

I have implemented periodic polling for data from ElasticSearch at NodeJS server, but that does not sound to me as an efficient solution, and think event based solution would be far more efficient.

I googled for a way to subscribe to ElasticSearch from NodeJS server for data updates (based on filter specified on UI), but could not find any.

Is there any better approach to handle this? Something like ElasticSearch(or Kafka for that matter - but NOT using Kafka Streaming API) pushing data updates?

Comment: ElasticSearch might sound like an unnecessary hop, but we need it for Kibana UI

Comment: Out of interest, why are you specifically excluding Kafka Streams API from consideration?

Answer (score 0):

It is [not yet possible](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/14976#issuecomment-159372486) to stream changes out of Elasticsearch.

- Here is the issue: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/1242
- It is blocking on https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/10708